# Can I get good performance when searching a large oracle table for a list of values?

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, database-performance

I'm trying to improve the performance of a project I'm working on and have found that the biggest bottleneck is in a certain query.

```
select bar from foo where bar in (:bars);
```

The query's purpose is simply to bounce a bunch of values for bar off the foo table to see which bars are in there and which are not. The foo table is HUGE and this query takes at least 10 minutes, even with only 5 bars in the input list.

Now here's another query that only works for one bar:

```
select case when exists (select 1 from foo.bar where bar = 'value') then 'Y' else 'N' end from dual;
```

This runs in a small fraction of a second and gets me the information I need.

The difference in explain plans between the two queries are that the first uses a 'fast full scan' and the second uses a 'skip scan'. The bar column is indexed if that matters.

The question is, how if at all can I get a query that runs with the performance of the second query but allows me to throw multiple bars at it like the first query? It's important to me because it's common to have 10k-100k bars at once to check, and not only do the fractions of a second add up but each database connection is a point of failure.

EDIT: Also in case it matters, the query is being run in Java, specifically with the org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate class. I get the same performance measures whether I run the query via the Java or I run it in SQL Developer.

Comment: Add an index based on bar

Comment: Insert bars you are looking for into a separate table and use inner join between foo and that table

Comment: You might try:  select distinct(bar) from foo where bar in (:bars);   Your query won't return every single matching row.

Comment: What is the :bars bind variable value (example)?  Because if you think it is a comma-separated string, that will not work.

Comment: trilogy - as stated in the question, unless I am misunderstanding your comment, there is an index on bar.
Ivan - unfortunately won't be possible. The account lacks permission to create tables or even temp tables. It can only perform selects, inserts, deletes, and updates.
Jamie - I'll try that.
OldProgrammer - you can replace bars with a list of strings, e.g., select bar from foo where bar in ('bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3', 'bar4', 'bar5');

Comment: Jamie - the query still took 10 minutes with just one value of bar. It was a nice thought though.
OldProgrammer - I don't know why I told you it's a list of strings. It's a list of numbers. So an example is "select bar from foo where bar in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think kanagaraj had the right idea, but the query was still as slow as it ever was because there's still a "select bar from foo" in there that triggers the fast full scan. A modified version of the query, however, gives me the performance I'm seeking (and of course, expected results).

```
with cte as (
select 1, case when exists (select null from foo where bar = 1) then 'Y' else 'N' end from dual
union all
select 2, case when exists (select null from foo where bar = 2) then 'Y' else 'N' end from dual
union all
...
)
select * from cte;
```

I will keep the question open in case someone comes up with something more elegant, but thank you to those who kindly offered your help. I wouldn't have found a working solution without your input.

Comment: In practice, I gave the values in the inner selects aliases and then the outer select is "select bar from cte where bar_exists = 'Y'". The way it's written above doesn't require the outer select at all.

Answer (score 0):

With all your restrictions for index and table ..Try this below query if its one time activity: if its dynamic build this as CTE like below and try

```
with cte
as
(select 1 bar from dual
union all 
select 2 from dual
union all
select 3 from dual
union all
select 4 from dual
union all
select 5 from dual)

select bar from foo where  exists(select bar from cte where cte.bar=foo.bar);
```

Comment: It can be simplified to `SELECT 1 FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT 2 FROM dual ...`

Comment: got you Ivan ... agreed